# How to change the wp_upload_dir() path in plugin

Tags: plugins, customization, uploads

I am using one plugin to upload all the client files. By default all the uploading files stored in the path wp-content/uploads/-plugin-name- . How to  store all my files in my custom directory that somewhere in root of wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

The upload directory and URL paths are stored in the options database. You can change them using `update_option()`:

```
update_option( 'upload_path', ABSPATH . '/path/to/uploads' );
update_option( 'upload_path_url', site_url( '/uploads/' ) );
```

However, it's best not to use this in a publiuc plugin, as it will cause numerous issues. We can instead hook into the filters that control the result of getting these options and set them to our custom paths:

```
function wpse_84046_upload_path( $path ) {
    return '/path/to/uploads';
}
add_filter( 'pre_option_upload_path', 'wpse_84046_upload_path' );

function wpse_84046_upload_path_url( $url ) {
    return site_url( '/uploads/' );
}
add_filter( 'pre_option_upload_path_url', 'wpse_84046_upload_path_url' );
```

Comment: Take a look at the wp-config.php and the constants there. This shouldn't get changed inside a plugin...

Comment: @kaiser They're not *being changed*, we're just using `ABSPATH` to get the WordPress root directory

Comment: Assuming that you're using `wp_upload_dir()` and such, you should use this during calling it, not setting. Use `'pre_option_upload_path'` to set a path relative to the `ABSPATH`. When you're changing this from a plugin you'll anyway have dozens of problems. Especially when already got files in the original directory.

Comment: @kaiser Good point. I guess I was referring to a one-time change; I'll update my answer